# glfw3 window freezes after random amount of time

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, raspberry-pi, glfw

I have an issue with some basic glfw and opengl code not running as expected. The window freezes completely only after at least a few seconds, some times much more.

I have commented almost all my code and is left with very few lines.

the init function is :

```
int Renderer::init(std::string scene_file_ , RenderOptions options_)
{

    if(!glfwInit()){
        std::cout<<"Problem with GLFW"<< std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640,480, "raytracer", NULL, NULL);

    if(!window){
        std::cout << "Problem with window " << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    glfwSwapInterval(2);
    glewInit();
}
```

and the drawing loop is :

```
void Renderer::displayScene()
{


    GLCall(glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST));
    int width, height;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    GLCall(glViewport(0,0,width, height));

    GLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT));
    GLCall(glClearColor(0.2,0.5,0.2,1.0));      

    printf("drawing %d\n", temp_inc_test++);

    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(renderer.window);
}
```

The window starts fine, the background is of the right color, and then after between ~3secs and ~5mins, the program stops, the window becomes unresponsive.
I am pretty sure I have run some code exactly like that, and it ran fine for hours on. I don't get it.

Anything obvious ?
I forgot to mention : I am on rasberry PI on linux Jessie

Comment: Have you ruled out thermal issues on the device?

Comment: Yes pretty much, when it happens cpu and gpu are not even at 53 degrees C , no worries there I think

Comment: What is doing `GlCall`?

Comment: It'as a macro to manage opengl errors :

Comment: I tried without it, and the result is the same unfortunatly